# Change HTTP response body right before sending

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I want to give a client the possibility to dynamically select only certain columns of the entities to query when communicating with our rpc API. For example by specifying an array of strings with the fields to select with point notation for navigation properties.

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method":  "getEntity",
    "params": {
        "id": 2,
        "fields": ["name", "SubEntityList.name"]
    },
    "id": "123-456"
}
```

As it is not (possible?) that easy to dynamically select with Entity Framework and the db and the app are running on the same server, I don't care about the selects while fetching data from the db. The response-body however is supposed to only carry the given fields.

Now I know that you can register new MessageHandlers in the WebApiConfig file to later alter responses for example. But at this point I don't have access to the actual json which will be sent, but only to the object where I'm obviously not able to remove fields.

**Question:**

Is there a way to hook into the response building process at a point where I can access the response-body already being serialized (json), right before it will be sent?

Comment: what i understood is that you want to change the response of the API ? Right ? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: That's right, but I'd like to get the response-body after serialization, in json. Then make some changes and send (return) it.

Comment: can you share a piece of code where you are doing things in your controller action method, So accordingly i can answer your question.